# Glibcxx error compiling FREAK OpenCV demo file

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, opensuse

i have tried out this file to compile with

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>

using namespace cv;

static void help( char** argv )
{
    std::cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0] << " [path/to/image1] [path/to/image2] \n"
              << "This is an example on how to use the keypoint descriptor presented in the following paper: \n"
              << "A. Alahi, R. Ortiz, and P. Vandergheynst. FREAK: Fast Retina Keypoint. \n"
              << "In IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 2012.     CVPR 2012 Open Source Award winner \n"
              << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    // check http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html
    // for OpenCV general detection/matching framework details

    if( argc != 3 ) {
        help(argv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Load images
    Mat imgA = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    if( !imgA.data ) {
        std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading image " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat imgB = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    if( !imgB.data ) {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading image " << argv[2] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypointsA, keypointsB;
    Mat descriptorsA, descriptorsB;
    std::vector<DMatch> matches;

    // DETECTION
    // Any openCV detector such as
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(2000,4);

    // DESCRIPTOR
    // Our proposed FREAK descriptor
    // (roation invariance, scale invariance, pattern radius corresponding to         SMALLEST_KP_SIZE,
    // number of octaves, optional vector containing the selected pairs)
    // FREAK extractor(true, true, 22, 4, std::vector<int>());
    FREAK extractor;

    // MATCHER
    // The standard Hamming distance can be used such as
    // BruteForceMatcher<Hamming> matcher;
    // or the proposed cascade of hamming distance using SSSE3
    BruteForceMatcher<Hamming> matcher;

    // detect
    double t = (double)getTickCount();
    detector.detect( imgA, keypointsA );
    detector.detect( imgB, keypointsB );
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "detection time [s]: " << t/1.0 << std::endl;

    // extract
    t = (double)getTickCount();
    extractor.compute( imgA, keypointsA, descriptorsA );
    extractor.compute( imgB, keypointsB, descriptorsB );
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "extraction time [s]: " << t << std::endl;

    // match
    t = (double)getTickCount();
    matcher.match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB, matches);
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "matching time [s]: " << t << std::endl;

    // Draw matches
    Mat imgMatch;
    drawMatches(imgA, keypointsA, imgB, keypointsB, matches, imgMatch);

    namedWindow("matches", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
    imshow("matches", imgMatch);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

with this command

```
gcc freak_demo.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

and received this error message

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:     /tmp/ccwSmrle.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSsD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: note:  '_ZNSsD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what GLIBCXX is. Which package (OpenSuse 13.1, gcc 4.8) do I have to install? I don't know how to interpret the error message, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this:  "_ZNSsD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line"?

Comment: Try `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073257/daniel-frey) said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171656/glibcxx-error-compiling-freak-opencv-demo-file#comment31872873_21171656), use `g++` instead of `gcc`. This solved the exact same problem for me, but for the compilation of a totally different program.